# Add field to an array where we map the company_id

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this arrays where i need to add another field with the company_count - where i get that from another array, but the problem is when i'm doing that if i have 5 results in the company_number because i'm unsetting them i will have only 5 results when i merge both of the arrays.
With this foreach i'm just grabbing the elements and adding in the first 5 results.

The rest of the arrays examples are here
https://pastebin.com/LbkmXmMt

As you can see when i merge both of the arrays i have company_number only on the first 5 results, right now i need to add the
first array

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '90557',
    'company_id' => '1537',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '71619',
    'company_id' => '257',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '87818',
    'company_id' => '7865',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '87824',
    'company_id' => '7865',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '87821',
    'company_id' => '7865',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '52912',
    'company_id' => '11682',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => '85963',
    'company_id' => '2485',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => '80716',
    'company_id' => '2485',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'id' => '79529',
    'company_id' => '2485',
  ),
)
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'company' => '1537',
    'company_number' => '1091',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'company' => '257',
    'company_number' => '111',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'company' => '7865',
    'company_number' => '33',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'company' => '11682',
    'company_number' => '18',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'company' => '2485',
    'company_number' => '165',
  ),
)
```

I need to add same company_number if i have a result with the same company id.
For example array with company id = 7865 should have company_number = 33, three times.

I need the result to be like this

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '90557',
    'company_id' => '1537',
    'company_number' => '1091'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '71619',
    'company_id' => '257',
    'company_number' => '111'
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => '87818',
    'company_id' => '7865',
    'company_number' => '33'
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => '87824',
    'company_id' => '7865',
    'company_number' => '33'
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => '87821',
    'company_id' => '7865',
    'company_number' => '33'
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'id' => '52912',
    'company_id' => '11682',
    'company_number' => '18'
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'id' => '85963',
    'company_id' => '2485',
    'company_number' => '165'
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'id' => '80716',
    'company_id' => '2485',
    'company_number' => '165'
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'id' => '79529',
    'company_id' => '2485',
    'company_number' => '165'
  ),
)
```

```
$test = array();    
        foreach($individual as $value){
            foreach($value as $j => $users) {
                foreach($company_numbers as $key => $company_num) {
                    if($users['company_id'] == $company_num['company']) {
                        
                        $test[]['company_number'] = $company_num['company_id'];
                        $test[] = $users;
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["company_number"]=>
    string(4) "1091"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "90557"
    ["company_id"]=>
    string(4) "1537"

  }
```

need this to be in the same array

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue. Your arrays there contain lots of items, that don’t appear to be relevant for the current problem - so please remove those, that will make this question much easier to understand, if we don’t have to sort through this much clutter.

Comment: need to map company from my second array with the company_id from first array and add company_number

Comment: Edited, now its only the data that i need in this situation.

Comment: Again, please present a _proper_ [mre], not “code here, arrays there – you people piece it together”. The way you have currently shown these arrays, we can not even just copy&paste them, because that is not valid PHP code. (Hint: `var_export` can produce valid PHP code from data structures such as arrays.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this.

First you need to loop the array with the Ids.

```
$companyIds = [
   ['company_id' => 1537],
   ['company_id' => 250],
   ['company_id' => 250]
];

$companyNumbers = [
   ['company' => 1537, 'company_number' => 33],
   ['company' => 250, 'company_number' => 100],
];

foreach ($companyIds as $key => $id) {
  foreach ($companyNumbers as $numbers) {
    if ($id['company_id'] == $numbers['company']) {
        $companyIds[ $key ]['company_number'] = $numbers['company_number'];
    }
  }
}
```

If you add the company Id as key for each entry in the company numbers array its simpler:

```
$companyIds2 = [  
    ['company_id' => 1537],
    ['company_id' => 250],
    ['company_id' => 250],
];

$companyNumbers2 = [
    1537 => ['company' => 1537, 'company_number' => 33],
    250  => ['company' => 250, 'company_number' => 100],
];

foreach ($companyIds2 as $key => $id) {
    if (array_key_exists( $id['company_id'], $companyNumbers2 )) {
        $companyIds2[ $key ]['company_number'] = $companyNumbers2[$id['company_id']]['company_number'];
    }
}
```

I hope thats the answer you are looking for.

Comment: added the result from this example in my original post

Comment: the problem is that now i'm creating a new array for the company_number @elzorro

Comment: found a way to make it work but your proposal put me on right track.